# Navigate to view controller from Tableview cell inside collectionview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

So I have tableview embedded in collectionview.
I have xib for tableview.
When user select a cell of tableview I want to navigate to another view controller.

I tried this method but its not working

```
let storyboardId = "Login"
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) 
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

But its not working because this viewcontroller in not added to navigation stack.

```
    class DetailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
//        let storyboardId = "Login"
//        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId)
//        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)


    }

}
```

How do i solve this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you are creating navigation controller which has nothing related to current navigation controller you can  Replace `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)` with `self.navigationController.push...`

Comment: self.navigationController.pushViewController is also throwing error.

Comment: Okay. You need to implement delegate  or protocol  from CollectionView Cell -> ViewController as DetailCollectionViewCell is not view controller so you can't push or present view controller from there

Comment: @dahiya_boy It is duplicate but your link is to answer is different from this one

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya First OP have to set root VC of Nav Controller. If NavController is created in window then he can directly push to next VC. Every thing is the answer, then how answer is different?

Comment: @dahiya_boy The problem is he wants to push view controller from collectionview cell (see the code posted by him) and you have posted a link which is not relevant as per me

Comment: @dahiya_boy Not an issue  :) This is often I used to :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have following options

1) Implement tableview datasource and delgate in viewController instead of collection view cell

2) Use Delegate  (explained below ) 
3) Use Closures  
4) Use NotificationCenter

You need to create delegate or protocol as collection view cell can't push or present view controller.

Here is simple example (This is not exact code you may need modification)

Create protocol

```
protocol TableViewInsideCollectionViewDelegate:class {
    func cellTaped(data:IndexPath)
}
```

Inside your collectionview cell add weak property

```
weak var delegate:TableViewInsideCollectionViewDelegate?
```

Now in your ViewController class you in cellForItem method of collectionview 
 you need to set delegate to self

like

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
```

and implement delegate method in viewController class and write code to push your view controller from there like `self.navigationController.push`

Now In Goto Collectionview Cell method

and whenever your tableviewDidSelect called

call delegate method like                 `self.delegate?.cellTaped(data: dataYouWantToPass)`

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to check some info:

- First:
  Check your `navigationController` is nil or not
- Second:
  Check your initial view controller method is correct or not,
  this is my way:

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

  let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryboardIdentifier") as? ViewController

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### You can solve this problem by using a delegation pattern use the following steps :

- Confirm table view delegate to the collection view and collection view delegate to the respective view controller.
- delegation chaining can be used to solve this problem. In this example, I have shown how you can pass data from table view cell to collection view cell.
- Implement collection view delegate and data source methods.
- Implement table view delegate and data source methods.
- whenever did select row will get called the call delegate method to tell view controller that some row is selected and according to the row index change handle your navigation.

code example:

- Step 1: Create a protocol.

  ```
  protocol RowSelected : class {
   func rowSelected(_ index : Int)
  }
  ```
- Step 2: Declare delegate variable in TableViewCell.

  ```
  weak var delegate: RowSelected?
  ```
- Step 3: In collection view confirm delegate and Implement delegated method.

  ```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

    extension CollectionViewCell : RowSelected {
       func rowSelected() {
        // Pass the information to view controller via a delegate/closure/notification. just like we passed information from table view cell to collection view cell and handle navigation accordingly.
       }
    }
  ```
- Step 4: In ViewController you can confirm a delegate for collection view and implement it's delegate method and can handle navigation.

You can use a closure and notification center as well to inform view controller to navigate to next screen.